# How to fix broken Photoshop displacement filter

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

My displacement filter is simply broken.  I made the simplest possible grid for a test subject, and then a displacement filter which is **solid 50% grey**.  This should, as a displacement map, do absolutely nothing.  But when I apply it, it produces the transformation shown below.  It's moving the lines around, fading then, and it also adds horrible pixelation in the middle.  This from a map that should have no effect at all!  What's causing this and what can I do about it?  Thanks.

[image: Test Pattern]  [image: Test Pattern Displaced]

**Update**: Here's a PNG of the displacement map, as requested (sorry it's so boring, but I did say it was a totally neutral map):

[image]

Comment: Have you tried resetting preferences/settings?

Comment: Could you upload a PNG of the displacement map?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: Yes, I've updated the question with a PNG of the map.

Comment: @Scott: I just tried it now and the same thing happens.

Comment: Who made the down vote, and why?

Comment: is it a single channel or dual channel displacement map file? Note that I can duplicate the offset by using -50,-50 offsets, but I don't see the corruption in the center area.

Comment: It's a single channel image.  I tried making a two channel map, with both channels all grey, but I get the same problem.  I'm not sure I follow you about duplicating my problem.  If I had random pixels in the map, I'd expect random pixels in the transformed grid, but my map is solid, and my problem is that I can't figure out where the noise is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

when I take your grid, and then create a 2-channel displacement map, I can mimic your problem using the following:

(-50,-50,tile,wrap around)

Channel 1, Channel 2: (The filter image looks plain grey, even when exporting)

[image]
[image]

Final image:

[image]